# Tensorflow LSTM: Input data is of wrong dimension

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

My tensor training data set structure is as follows:

```
[[1  3  0  99  4 ... 9  0  9],
...
[3  2  3  1  3 ... 9  9  8]]
```

In which there are 798 "rows" or individual arrays and each array is of length 9000, or has 9000 "columns".
The label data is like this: `[ [1 0 1 0 0 ... 0 0 0 1]]`. It is one array with 798 columns.

```
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100,batch_input_shape=(798,1000,9000)))
    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(training_data,training_labels,batch_size=150,epochs=10,validation_data=(validation_data,validation_labels))
```

But I kept getting the error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 9000]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Should I specify the `batch_input_shape`? Should I specify the `input_shape`? What do samples, batch size, time step, and features mean in relation to my data?

Comment: LSTMs are for sequence data, this does not look like sequence data, so why are you trying to use an LSTM for it?

Comment: Your data needs to be 3D and `(798, 1000, 9000)`. But you're passing a 2D (None, 9000) dataset.